# php adodb MSSQL connection

Tags: php, sql-server, adodb-php

I have a linux server that I'm trying to use php adodb to connect to a MSSQL server.

```
include('adodb5/adodb.inc.php'); 

$conn =& ADONewConnection('odbc_mssql');
$dsn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=MSSERVER;Database=Northwind;";
$conn->Connect($dsn,'sa','password')or die("Unable to connect to server");
```

I've install mssql through yum etc and I know the server can connect to it as I've tried the following:

```
$db = @mssql_connect("MSSERVER","sa","password") or die("Unable to connect to server");
mssql_select_db("Northwind");

// Do a simple query, select the version of 
// MSSQL and print it.
$version = mssql_query('SELECT @@VERSION');
$row = mssql_fetch_array($version);

echo $row[0];

// Clean up
mssql_free_result($version);
```

Any ideas why my adodb wont connect, or any examples on how I can connect would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved this by looking at this forum: http://ourdatasolution.com/support/discussions.html?topic=4200.0

The correct code is:

```
<?php
include("adodb5/adodb.inc.php"); 
//create an instance of the  ADO connection object
$conn =&ADONewConnection ('mssql');
//define connection string, specify database driver
$conn->Connect('xxx.xxx.x.xxx:1400', 'user', 'password', 'DbName');
//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "select * from table";
$rs = $conn->execute($query);
//execute the SQL statement and return records
$arr = $rs->GetArray();
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Hope that helps somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

With php 5.3 of above the `php_mssql` modul is no longer supported for windows.

A Solution is to download the MicroSoft PHP Driver from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098.

This installer will extract the modul dll files to you php extension directory.

Include the correct version in you php ini (e.g. like this for php 5.3 ThreadSafe):

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
```

After this you can use adboDb again, but you have to use `mssqlnative` as adodbtype.
And the connection with ip and port didnt work for me, but `ipaddress\\SERVERNAME` worked (see examplecode)

```
<?php include("adodb5/adodb.inc.php");  
//create an instance of the  ADO connection object
$conn =&ADONewConnection ('mssqlnative'); 
//define connection string, specify database driver 

// $conn->Connect('xxx.xxx.x.xxx:1400', 'user', 'password', 'DbName'); 
$conn->Connect('xxx.xxx.x.xxx\\SERVERNAME', 'user', 'password', 'DbName'); 

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database 
$query = "select * from table"; 
$rs = $conn->execute($query); 
//execute the SQL statement and return records 
$arr = $rs->GetArray(); 
print_r($arr); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 7.4 you can download the drivers here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Copy the files to the ext directory of your php installation.
In the php.ini file then add the extensions as follows:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64
extension=php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64
```

The extension also requires the ODBC driver for SQL Server to be installed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15